# Unknown Provider - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have seen a lot of topic like that, but i didn't find solution.

I'm getting this error Error:

> $injector:unpr Unknown Provider
>
> Unknown provider: restaurantsProvider <- restaurants <- restaurantsController

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('restaurantsController', restaurantsController);

    restaurantsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'restaurants']; 

    function restaurantsController($scope, restaurants) {

        $scope.restaurants = restaurants.query();
    }
})();
```

And service file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var restaurantsService = angular.module('restaurantsService', ['ngResource']);

    restaurantsService.factory('restaurantsService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/restaurants', {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
            });
        }]);
})();
```

If it affects on something, I'm using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates that you are trying to inject something that angular doesn't know about. There are a few issues I'm seeing with your app structure which are leading to this issue...

1. You never actually declare your "myApp" module which is where you need to inject your restaurantService app.
2. Your controller takes in a 'restaurant' dependency but the service is actually called 'restaurantsService'

I would expect the app structure to look something like this:

```
    (function () {
        'use strict';

        var restaurantsServiceApp = angular.module('restaurantsServiceApp', ['ngResource']);

        restaurantsServiceApp.factory('restaurantsService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
                return $resource('/api/restaurants', {}, {
                    query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
                });
            }]);
    })();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['restaurantsServiceApp']);
    myApp.controller('restaurantsController', restaurantsController);

    restaurantsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'restaurantsService']; 

    function restaurantsController($scope, restaurantsService) {

        $scope.restaurants = restaurantsService.query();
    }
})();
```

Your serviceApp needs to be declared prior to it being injected in the other app.

Comment: That was a key: "Your serviceApp needs to be declared prior to it being injected in the other app." In my app.js, I forget to add 'restaturantsService'.

_var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', **'restaurantsService'**]);_